# Python - SQLITE db update entrys from csv file

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, sql-update

I am trying to update existing sqlite db rows with rows from my csv file.
Not delet and insert, but update existing row (keeping id).

dqlite db has 4 columns and only 4th column is different (to update).
if its not possible to update only one column i can accept updating whole row but keeping its place in db.

**db before update:**

```
cfthostname,cftshortname,cftenv,cert_time
1904h.net,1904h,tst,DD/MM/RRRR
19053.net,19053,tst,26/03/2021
2210010315.net,2210010315,prd,DD/MM/RRRR
1809m.net,1809m,tst,26/03/2021
13jw.net,13jw,acc,DD/MM/RRRR
```

**csv to update:**

```
cfthostname,cftshortname,cftenv,cert_time
1904h.net,1904h,tst,13/05/2023
19053.net,19053,tst,23/07/2023
13jw.net,13jw,acc,14/06/2029
```

**update code**:

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect("C:\db.sqlite3")
cursor = conn.cursor() 
[...]
with open('C:\\csv\\update.csv','rt') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['hostname'], i['shortname'], i['env'], i['cert_time']) for i in dr]

cursor.executemany("UPDATE itpassed_host SET hostname = ?, shortname = ?, env = ?, cert_time = ?", to_db)
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

tried also with **()** on *to_db* but it gives same output on db

```
cursor.executemany("UPDATE itpassed_host SET hostname = ?, shortname = ?, env = ?, cert_time = ?", (to_db))
```

**db after update:**

```
cfthostname,cftshortname,cftenv,cert_time
13jw.net,13jw,acc,14/06/2029
13jw.net,13jw,acc,14/06/2029
13jw.net,13jw,acc,14/06/2029
13jw.net,13jw,acc,14/06/2029
13jw.net,13jw,acc,14/06/2029
```

how to update only rows from **csv to update** correctly in db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `WHERE` condition.

```
import sqlite3
import csv

conn = sqlite3.connect("db.sqlite3")
cursor = conn.cursor() 
with open('update.csv','rt') as fin:
    dr = csv.DictReader(fin)
    to_db = [(i['cert_time'], i['cfthostname'], i['cftshortname'], i['cftenv'],) for i in dr]

cursor.executemany("UPDATE itpassed_host SET cert_time = ? WHERE cfthostname = ? AND cftshortname = ? AND cftenv = ?", to_db)
conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Notice the order changed in the line with `to_db=`.